# Sed with tab and negate match

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following file

```
a
b   c   d   e
```

all are tab separated.

my output should be the following

```
a,
b,c,d,e
```

i was trying following methods.

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*/,/g' input.txt
this gives me the following
,a,
,b,c,d,e,
```

How should i remove the first comma of both lines. so the output should be like this

a,
   b,c,d,e,

managed to do the following but with two sed commands.

```
cat input.txt |  sed 's/[[:space:]]*/,/g' | sed 's/^,//'  (sorry useless use of cat)
```

Is there  a better way to do this with one sed command. (i'm not looking for awk/tr or any other method, only sed )

Comment: `[[:space:]]*` matches a space character zero or more times. So it would matches a zero width boundary before or after to a  character.

Comment: what do you think about this ? sed 's/\t/,/g' input.txt  . this didn't change anything.

Comment: You would like to have `,` after `a`, but not after `e`?

Comment: @TharangaAbeyseela may i know the reason for unaccepting my answer? And also your recent accepted answer will add a comma after `e`. Check his command one more time.

Comment: Sorry, lagivan's answer is more general i think. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition that there are some letters before the space:

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\+\)[[:space:]]*/\1,/g' input.txt
```

Chain two sed rules in one command (this way may be more readable):

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*/,/g;s/^,//' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,\n/g;s/ \+/,/g' file
a,
b,c,d,e
```

**OR**

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,\n/g;s/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g' file
```